# Unity - Problem with Google Play Services Leaderboard get user rank

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, leaderboard

I have an issue with the Google Play Services Leaderboard and I am stuck for days already.

I am using the [Play Games Plugin for Unity](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity).

I am trying to get the Userrank for a specific level. Therefore I am loading the Scores via the LoadScores Function and this seems to work fine.

The issue seems to be, that I get a correct rank in the "LoadScores" Function but the overall `GetUserRank` Function is still returning rank = 0, no matter what the actual Userrank is.

My guess is that this is a timing issue after all and that the rank is returned before the LoadScores Function has calculated the correct rank to return.

```cs
public int GetUserRank(string levelID)
{
    int rank = 0;
    string user = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.localUser.id;
    string leaderboard = ReturnLeaderboard(levelID);
    Social.LoadScores(leaderboard, scores =>
    {
        if (scores.Length > 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Retrieved " + scores.Length + " scores");

            //Filter the score with the user name
            for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)
            {
                if (user == scores[i].userID)
                {
                    rank = scores[i].rank;
                    // This prints out the actual rank of the user and seems to work
                    print("Rank in LoadScoresFunction: " + rank);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
            Debug.Log("Failed to retrieved score");
    });
    //Here the rank is always 0, no matter the outcome of the LoadScores Function above
    print("Rank in PlayGamesController: " + rank);
    return rank;
}
```

I reference this function from other scripts via:

```cs
int rank = PlayGamesController.Instance.GetUserRank(levelID);
```

Any ideas/hints greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like `LoadScores` is exuted **async** so you `return rank;` before even getting a result, so it stays `0`.

Instead of directly assigning the value you will probably have to work with a callback instead:

```
public void GetUserRank(string levelID, Action<int> onResult)
{
     var user = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.localUser.id;
     var leaderboard = ReturnLeaderboard(levelID);
     Social.LoadScores(leaderboard, scores =>
     {
         if (scores.Length > 0)
         {
             Debug.Log("Retrieved " + scores.Length + " scores");

             //Filter the score with the user name
             for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)
             {
                 if (user == scores[i].userID)
                 {
                     var rank = scores[i].rank;
                     // This prints out the actual rank of the user and seems to work
                     print("Rank in LoadScoresFunction: " + rank);

                     onResult?.Invoke (result);
                     break;
                 }
             }
         }
         else
             Debug.Log("Failed to retrieved score");
             onResult?.Invoke(-1);
     });
 }
```

And then use it like e.g. using a callback method

```
private void OnReceivedResult(int rank)
{
    // Do something with rank
}

...

PlayGamesController.Instance.GetUserRank(levelID, OnReceivedResult);
```

Or using a lambda expression

```
PlayGamesController.Instance.GetUserRank(levelID, rank => {
    // Do something with rank
});
```